# Binding to two dependency properties of the user control which is a ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I've created an user control which is a ListViewItem. That control has 2 dependency properties I would like to bind to from my ViewModel. But how am I supposed to do that when I can only bind one thing (collection) to ListView ItemsSource property? How can I bind to ExpanderInfo dependency property? Is there any way to do that or maybe I have made a bad assumption and should have created user control in other way?

Here is my xaml code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTask}" Height="200" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <tc:TaskTile TaskInfo="{Binding}" ExpanderInfo="{Binding ExpanderStatus}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What you are trying to bind and to which Property ?

Comment: I have a ViewModel which contains Tasks collection and ExpanderStatus bool value. I want to bind Tasks collection to TaskInfo property, and ExpanderStatus to ExpanderInfo property. TaskInfo binding works well because of ItemsSource binding. But there is a problem with ExpanderStatus binding like it has no connection with ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `<tc:TaskTile TaskInfo="{Binding}" ExpanderInfo="{Binding ExpanderStatus}"/>` with

`<tc:TaskTile TaskInfo="{Binding}" ExpanderInfo="{Binding DataContext.ExpanderStatus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView, Mode=FindAncestor}}"/>`

Comment: Wow, it works!
Now I understand what it is all about. Thank you!